# What is the recommended reading list for new SO users?

Tags: support, help, documentation

I didn't really see much using that search term.  In making a number of posts related new user issues I received some good suggestions.  Of course what is relevant are the items that go beyond the information in the help center.

I put them in an answer here to match the Q&A format.  I still need to add the links recommended in those posts and pages, add any recommendations here and clean it up.

Does this already exist but not using the term "recommended reading?"  For example, **Should the FAQ simply have a new user section?**

If a new users recommended read list should exist here, what should be added to the list below?

Should this new users list also have a list of topics?  I.E. One for duplicate questions, one for voting, one for question quality.

Thanks, I thought something should at least exist with "recommended reading" in the title which could of course link to another post. I am really ambivalent here.

The FAQ is comprehensive and is THE recommended list for new users really.  In doing a search, this post actually bumped the FAQ down one position whereas I think FAQ should be the first result.

On the other hand, I don't know when users change the FAQ, how often the changes are accepted, and if they should have a separate place to make their own recommendations specific to new users.

Difficult, See Cody Gray's comment below and I also quote:
"The FAQ for Stack Exchange sites is under our (ordinary users) control, it's our responsibility to edit it. – Sha Wiz Dow Ard"

Comment: Duplicate of the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)?

Comment: @Mat, I think it is different in not being a page.  Something that the community could dynamically add to.  If this is incorrect I should in this case delete the post.  Do users actually edit the FAQ?  Perhaps this should merely point to the FAQ.

Comment: @Mat I'm really not sure what to do but altered the question to reflect your good point.  I think this should maybe be deleted.  Perhaps a moderator, you, or another power user should make that call.  Perhaps this post should merely point out how extensive the FAQ is and that it includes posts from users...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but...yes, users can edit the FAQ that Mat linked (and each of the questions/answers to which *it* links). They are all marked "community wiki".

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended reading for new users.**

[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

[Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)

[What should I do if my feature request is a duplicate of a previous one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189741/what-should-i-do-if-my-feature-request-is-a-duplicate-of-a-previous-one/189764?noredirect=1#comment586713_189764)

[New, Improved Comments with @reply](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)

[Why must I wait two days before accepting my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer)

[A way to increase Positive contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180985/a-way-to-increase-positive-contributions)

[Mark a comment as the answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

[Difficulty finding existing / duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63155/difficulty-finding-existing-duplicate-questions)

[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: Well, asking new users to read [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) is like asking new C++ programmers to read [The C++ Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language)

Comment: @doubleDown Humorous.  I must confess the FAQ is a little intimidating and thought a shorter list, maybe sorted by reading order and also oriented on new users might help that.

Comment: @doubleDown I added "Should the FAQ have a new user section?" to the question.  This might help address the problem and keep them on the FAQ page.